# How do I grep out lines above til certain pattern is found

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I need to grep out lines matching certain parameter from the file and then above that pattern til the time "#" is found at the beginning of the line.

For example here is the file and I need filter out "00:21:44" and lines above that till # is found.

Any clue?

```
# CSV: Date,Score,URL,IP                                                             #
######################################################################################
"06-07-19 00:23:46","4.5","www.origina-l-diploms.com/wp-includes/fonts/mtbonline/update.htm","198.252.101.174"
"06-07-19 00:23:16","4.5","www.deehhayus.com/sqL/img/home/amazon","202.182.120.120"
"06-07-19 00:22:44","5.9","www.bricktechindia.in/fonts/www.bancoestado.cl/imagenes/comun2008/banca-en-linea-personas.html","43.255.154.40"
"06-07-19 00:22:14","3.7","www.bekenjekleurinstijl.nl/wp-admin/Alibaba/vqcr8bp0gud&lc=1033&id=64855&mkt=en-us&cbcxt=mai&snsc.php?email=nobody@mycraftmail.com","37.46.194.80"
"06-07-19 00:21:44","7.7","www.search-5.com/apx26e/verification/N76C72ED2B98CM9A99BC/qes.php","162.241.130.152"
```

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: `till #`, is that including that line? Something like `tac file| sed -n '/00:21:44/,/#/ p'| tac` matching the last 00:21:44 or do you wan't to match the first?

Answer (score -1):

Do that this `For example here is the file and I need filter out "00:21:44" and lines above that till # is found.` I like to filter out all from `#` to `00:21:44`?

If so, this should do:

Example data:

```
"06-07-19 00:24:16","4.5","www.deehhayus.com/sqL/img/home/amazon","202.182.120.120"
# CSV: Date,Score,URL,IP                                                             #
######################################################################################
"06-07-19 00:23:46","4.5","www.origina-l-diploms.com/wp-includes/fonts/mtbonline/update.htm","198.252.101.174"
"06-07-19 00:23:16","4.5","www.deehhayus.com/sqL/img/home/amazon","202.182.120.120"
"06-07-19 00:22:44","5.9","www.bricktechindia.in/fonts/www.bancoestado.cl/imagenes/comun2008/banca-en-linea-personas.html","43.255.154.40"
"06-07-19 00:22:14","3.7","www.bekenjekleurinstijl.nl/wp-admin/Alibaba/vqcr8bp0gud&lc=1033&id=64855&mkt=en-us&cbcxt=mai&snsc.php?email=nobody@mycraftmail.com","37.46.194.80"
"06-07-19 00:21:44","7.7","www.search-5.com/apx26e/verification/N76C72ED2B98CM9A99BC/qes.php","162.241.130.152"
"06-07-19 00:20:16","4.5","www.deehhayus.com/sqL/img/home/amazon","202.182.120.120"
```

Result

```
awk '/#/{f=1;print} !f; /00:21:44/{f=0}' file
"06-07-19 00:24:16","4.5","www.deehhayus.com/sqL/img/home/amazon","202.182.120.120"
# CSV: Date,Score,URL,IP                                                             #
######################################################################################
"06-07-19 00:20:16","4.5","www.deehhayus.com/sqL/img/home/amazon","202.182.120.120"
```